# Recommendation of books to setup and admin a web server in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, books

I am going to setup and admin a web server in Ubuntu Linux distribution. I installed it by default setting, and seems all works fine, and now I need to setup it to be a virtual web host server, mainly I will create more accounts and for each account, I will setup its home/folder, and ftp, so the user with the account can upload their PHP scripts to it, also I would like to make home/bin, home/lib for the account, so they can use SSH too, to install local binary or libs, even more..

I am thinking to read some books, but I don't know which one is good for me basically it could have something about how to setup virtual web host server, admin it, and how to make it secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy working through online tutorials I would reccomend looking at the Linode documentation library. You don't need to have a Linode server to make use of their articles and they cover a wide range of subjects.

http://library.linode.com/

If you're craving some structure to your learning process then I suggest you use the RHCSA exam objectives to point you in the right direction. Even thought the exam objectives are focussed on Red Hat systems they are useful for giving you a rough idea of what you need to learn. This won't focus on web server specifics but it will cover some very useful topics.

http://www.redhat.com/training/courses/ex200/examobjective